# To check whether the following function is coercive

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by
\begin{equation}
F(\textbf{x})=\alpha|\textbf{x}|^2+\beta\phi(f)(x_1+x_4)^2
\end{equation}
where $\alpha,\beta$ are postive constants, $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a monotone increasing function, $\textbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4), |\textbf{x}|^2=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2$. How to check whether this function is coercive or not, i.e. $F(\textbf{x})\ge a_0|\textbf{x}|^2+a_1$. Is there any direct way ?

Comment: Is $\phi$ monotone increasing or decreasing?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add. I have edited it. It's monotone increasing.

Answer (score 0):

For a function to be coercive, we just need to show that as $|\textbf x|\rightarrow +\infty$ then $f(\textbf x) \rightarrow +\infty$.

Now, if $|\textbf x| \rightarrow +\infty$, then at least one coordinate is going to infinity in norm (e.i $|x_i|\rightarrow +\infty$ for $i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$).

It is clear that $\alpha |\textbf x|^2$ goes to infinity as $|\textbf x|$ goes to infinity. Therefore, we only need to prove that $\beta \phi((x_1 + x_4)^2))$ does not go to $-\infty$.

As $|\textbf x| \rightarrow +\infty$, it is clear that $\beta \phi(f(\textbf x))$ does not go to $-\infty$, because, since $\phi$ is monotone increasing, than $$\beta\phi(y_n)\rightarrow  -\infty \implies y_n \rightarrow -\infty$$
that would imply that $(x_1 + x_4)^2 \rightarrow -\infty$, which is impossible.

Comment: One point is here $\phi(f)$ is a weighted constant which has a particular use. The function $f$ does not depend on $\textbf{x}$. Can the answer be now modified ?

Comment: I thought $f(x) = (x_1 + x_4)^2$, this is not the case?

Comment: that is not the case. You can think of $\beta\phi(f)$ as a weighted constant.

Comment: Could you give an explicit example of $\phi(f)((x_1 + x_4)^2)$? I don't understand what the function $f$ looks like.

Comment: You can take $\phi(f)=f^2$ for example.

Comment: But what about the function $f$? What can you tell me about it? Because if $f(x) = -x$, for example, then the proof does not work.